# Chrome Extension: Open window when running in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I have my chrome extension, runs in background fine. And every few hours it uses the notification API to ask the user a question.

If they click one answer we open a tab in the current window.

Problem: If there are no chrome windows open (i.e. the extension is running as part of "Let google chrome run in the background" option), the tab doesn't open.

Here's the code which works fine as long as there is at least a single chrome window open:

```
// tried this too: chrome.windows.create();
chrome.tabs.create({url: pathToGo});
```

How to make "chrome.windows.create()" actually make a window if there are none already open.

Comment: It seems like expected behavior for me. What does error console for background page reports? Maybe you could queue you tab.create request and wait while user decides to reopen the browser?

Comment: Yeah this is what I think - they don't want you to be forcing open windows.

Comment: And can't see console, as having inspector open counts as a window so it works fine.

Comment: You could reopen Chrome and open you background page. I believe console will have all messages still

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the user would want chrome opening and doing a popup when they may think they have it closed? I definitely wouldn't unless it was something very important (asking a question doesn't sound important...).

Comment: Audjrey - I'll keep trying, but best I can tell the messages are cleared by the time I can open the inspector again.

judgeja - It's an internal business extension, but in any case the question is basically "do you need to go to the website now?", so yes the user does want the window to open.

Thanks all, I'm putting this down to "they don't want you to do it" and giving it a rest for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome.windows.getAll(object getInfo, function callback)` APIs to get all open windows.
If in the callback, the array of windows is empty, create a new window using `chrome.windows.create(object createData, function callback)`.

Use `chrome.notifications` API if you are unable to create new window.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html

Comment: Thanks, but as I commented in my snippet - I tried the chrome.windows.create() method already, and it only opens a new window if there is already another window open.

Comment: In that case it's better to use `chrome.notifications` APIs.